Can nginx server act as remove proxy of both https and http backend endpoints?
I have NGINX server acting as a reverse proxy. I want to listen on both ports 80 (http) and 443 (https). I expect the request paths for http and https to be distinct because they serve different information to the clients. /api/plain_http/xxxx and /api/ssl_http/yyyy
The former (http) will not serve anything sensitive, hence okay to be on http. The latter may include something sensitive, therefore we want to enforce TLS and authz/authn.
I am sure NGINX reverse proxy can do this, but I wanted to double confirm what the config file will look like to support this.

To confirm your query I believe Nginx can be configured to manage requests on both HTTP and HTTPS. We'll just need the necessary SSL Certificate and SSL Certificate key for HTTPS configuration.
Below is a sample configuration:
HTTP server block
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain.com;

    location /api/plain_http/ {
        # Proxy pass to the backend server handling HTTP requests
        proxy_pass http://backend_http_server;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

HTTPS server block
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name your_domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/certificate.key;

    location /api/ssl_http/ {
        # Add or remove Authenticate as per your requirement.
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        # Proxy pass to the backend server handling HTTPS requests
        proxy_pass http://backend_https_server;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Hope this helps!
